# how to replace empty double quotes with some value

Tags: sed

i have a xml with below syntax

```
<test key="NAME1" value="">
<test key="NAME2" value="">
```

How to replace value with empty string with some values based on the key name, using sed command. With something like this

```
<test key="NAME1" value="123">
<test key="NAME2" value="234">
```

Comment: Don't use `sed` to process XML, use an XML-aware tool.

Answer (score 1):

Use an XML-aware tool to process XML, `sed` is too simple for the job.

For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write:

```
my $values = {
    NAME1 => 123,
    NAME2 => 234,
};

open file.xml ;
for my $test in //test[@value=""] {
    my $key = $test/@key ;
    set $test/@value { $values->{$key} } ;
}
save :b ;
```